# UV mesh gets distorted in UV editor by scaling or moving

Tags: uv

After unwrapping a cylinder-type of object (seams marked) I get three islands (top/bottom/side). No distortion, works as expected.

BUT: As soon as **I select one island** (using the island selection tool, but it's the same problem with manual selection) **and press "S" or "G" the uv mesh gets strangly distorted** (some vertices are merged, distances between vertices change). The distortion starts **before I even actually move the mouse**.

EVEN STRANGER: **When I append the object into a new blender file, everything works just normal!**

So I opened the original file and in another blender session the new file in which I appended the object to. I've compared the UV editing screens trying to find any difference (snapping turned on/off, proportional editing on/off, local/global settings, etc.). I could not find anything!

I think there must be any function turned on causing this strange behaviour, but I can't find it.

I've also tried: 
- Closing/Re-Opening Blender using original file
- Re-Save original file
- Save original file giving it another name
- I even restarted my pc...

Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: From what you said it should not make a difference but to be sure in Object mode make sure the transforms for the object are reset. Ctrl-a

Comment: I've checked that (several times...). All transformations are applied.

Answer (score 0):

In the *UV* tab, disable *'*Snap to Pixels*'* under the *UV Dropdown*, that should fix it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and procedure. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the workflow and how it works. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Blender 3.5.1 :
Go to *UV > Round to Pixel* and set it to *Disabled*.